# How to print a matrix in clockwise order

Tags: java, matrix, puzzle

There is matrix for [x][y] order. i want to print its value in clockwise order[image: please see the picture to make this clear.]

I have tried several methods but unable to write the logic of the code. I'm trying it in java but logic is important so you can help me in any language.

Comment: Is the matrix a square?

Comment: it could be..but not necessary

Comment: but if you know the logic for a square matrix then please share

Comment: you can refer to this http://www.geeksforgeeks.org/print-a-given-matrix-in-spiral-form, only difference is that it's in anticlock, hope you can modifiy it according to your need

Answer (score 0):

When I read your post I've started to play so I'll post you my code maybe it will be halpful for you. I've did it for square if you want for rectangle one need separate stepX and stepY. SIZE would be input parameter in your case, I have it final static for test.

```
public class clockwise {

    private static final int SIZE = 3;

    public static void main(String[] args) {
//      int[][] test_matrix = {{1,2,3,4},{5,6,7,8},{9,10,11,12},{13,14,15,16}};
        int[][] test_matrix = {{1,2,3},{5,6,7},{9,10,11}};
        int[][] direction = {{1, 0},{0, 1},{-1, 0},{0, -1}}; //{x,y}

        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE; i++) {
            for(int j = 0; j < SIZE; j++)
                System.out.print(test_matrix[i][j] + "  ");
            System.out.println("");
        }


        int x = 0;
        int y = 0;
        int directionMove = 0; 
        int stepSize = SIZE;
        boolean changeStep = true;
        int stepCounter = 0;


        for(int i = 0; i < SIZE*SIZE; i++) {
            System.out.print(test_matrix[x][y] + "  ");
            stepCounter++;
            if (stepCounter % stepSize == 0) {
                directionMove++;
                directionMove = directionMove%4;
                if(changeStep) { //after first edge one need to decrees step after passing two edges
                    stepSize--;
                    changeStep = false;
                } else {
                    changeStep = true;
                }
                stepCounter = 0;
            }
            x += direction[directionMove][0];
            y += direction[directionMove][1];
        }   
    }
}
```